# ControlsFX AutoComplete, how does it work?

Tags: binding, javafx, custom-controls, controlsfx

I'm trying to use the **custom control TextField Auto Complete** of ControlsFX.

To do so I **bind a `TextField` to an `ObservableList`** :

```
AutoCompletionBinding<DataPointForIPP> autoCompletionBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchPlane.getSearchTextField(), listDataPoint.getObservableList());
```

It works great, except that **when my `ObservableList` is updated, this is not the case of my autocompletion**. So I have to call the binding again, *which has no sense, since a binding is supposed to adapt to a changed of my list*.

Did I miss something in the initilization ?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The method you are calling takes a `Collection`, which is not in general observable, not a JavaFX `ObservableList` specifically; so it is no surprised it does not bind to it. You probably want to use the [version that takes a `Callback<ISuggestionRequest, Collection>`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html#bindAutoCompletion-javafx.scene.control.TextField-javafx.util.Callback-) which will update the collection as the text changes.

Comment: Can you post an example of how `Callback<ISuggestionRequest, Collection>` works ? And if it's not working I will post an MCVE.

Comment: Please post an MCVE so others have an idea what you are trying to do.